# Phonehap-Cordova error message using the create command

Tags: cordova, error-handling, wsh

I have done all the necessary installations, the android sdk, java sdk, and so on.
Everything runs fine when I test them, java, android, javax, ant and so on.

But when I try to run the `Create` command from the cordova "getting started page" I get an exception. 
[image]

The annoying part is that, before it worked, but the error was that it said I was missing one of the , Android, Ant, of Java installations.

I made sure I had the right paths to all of them, and then I started getting this new error.

Anyone any idea how to fix it.

I run Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you might have messed up your path to CScript.exe when you were setting up your paths to android, ant and java.

In the windows environment you should be able to run `cscript` in the command line.

Double check you paths and make sure to add the path to CScript.exe if it isn't there, mine is in `C:\Windows\System32` which you should be able to see in your path variable.

**If you change your path you may need to restart for the changes to take affect**

[Or you could use this method](http://www.nerdydork.com/update-windows-path-without-rebooting.html)

Comment: Do you mean `cscript` should be in the path? I added this line to my path `C:\WINDOWS\system32`, plus I have enabled the registry for the Windows Host. I have added to the path, but nothing seems to happen. So strange since first time the error was different, it seems it actually run the script, now it does not even recognize it.

Comment: when you type `path` into the command prompt do you see the path to `C:\WINDOWS\system32`? If not, and your sure you added it to the environment variables maybe you need to restart for the changes to take effect.

Comment: You are them man dude, finally some light :) You are right the restart did the thing. Is funny how nobody else had mentioned that you need that line in the `path` Thanxxxx

Comment: Well I think it is automatically in the path unless you take it out, so in your case you were able to run the `create` command the first time because it was probably in the path and then when you went to add the android, ant and java paths you might have mistakenly deleted it.